# onStartCommand not called from MainActivity

Tags: android, service, bluetooth

i've tried the answers from similar questions. But only one fixed my problem, using:

```
startService(new Intent(this, BluetoothHelper.class));
```

But shouldn't binding my activity to my service be enough? 
Thanks a lot!

My BluetoothHelper class and MainActivity looks like this:

[GitHub link to BluetoothHelper class](https://github.com/LongDong279/AppGeruest3/blob/master/app/src/main/java/cesketronics/appgeruest3/BluetoothHelper.java)
[GitHub link to MainActivity](https://github.com/LongDong279/AppGeruest3/blob/master/app/src/main/java/cesketronics/appgeruest3/MainActivity.java)

Comment: You're asking a few different questions here. You may want to consider splitting out the "execute every minute" and "receive BT data every minute while app is minimized" topics into separate asks.
Also, it's not entirely clear what your main question is. Is it about `onStartCommand` not getting called? Or is it about restarting a service once it gets stopped?

Comment: Thanks will split it, 
my question at first is that onStartCommand is not getting called, only if i'm calling the startService method. Shouldn't binding be enough?

Comment: No. From the docs:
"Clients can also use Context.bindService() to obtain a persistent connection to a service. This likewise creates the service if it is not already running (calling onCreate() while doing so), but does not call onStartCommand()." I'll post that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting your service by using `bindService` (i.e. not using `startService`) will *not* call `onStartCommand`.

[From the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle):

> Clients can also use Context.bindService() to obtain a persistent connection to a service. This likewise creates the service if it is not already running (calling onCreate() while doing so), but does not call onStartCommand().

Comment: alright thanks, should i put all my code which is in onStartCommand in onCreate, or would this be "not nice"? Or should i do both, binding and using startService?

Comment: If you don't have any reason to use `startService`, then don't! Almost all logic you could put `onStartCommand` you can put in `onCreate`. There aren't any best practices that you'd be defying with that.

Comment: `onCreate()`  is not a good place to put your stuffs, because the service may have been alive before you call `startService()` or `bindService()`.
So, if you are using **Started** type of Service, put your code into `onStartCommand()`, or if you are using **Bound** type of Service, put your code into `onBind()`.
If you are using both, it's up to your requirements; you can use a combination of these two callback methods in a safe manner.

Comment: Very good point, @YUSMLE. I guess I was assuming (rather foolishly) that the code OP was putting in their `onStartCommand` callback was logic that should only be executed when the service was started/created. Thank you clarifying the best practices here!